# Is it neccessarry to shave the braces to get more volume w/ Lighter Strings?

Tags: guitar

I recently converted one of my Acoustic Guitars to get the full response w/ Magma Ultra-Light Gauge Acoustic Strings (9-46) & only those Strings by gently shaving down the braces (the ones inside the body) to be a teeny bit thinner, I also added a tailpiece for good measure. I found it necessary because it helps open up the sound a bit. Do you find it necessary to do this on your Acoustic Guitar?

Comment: Do you mean the braces inside the resonant chamber?

Comment: Yes & I had to do it gently.

Comment: Why did you feel you needed to do that? You can just put lighter strings on a guitar without altering it.

Comment: I've wanted to get the same amount of volume w/ lighter gauge strings as I had w/ heavier gauge strings by slightly altering it.

Comment: Typically Lighter Gauge strings don't have the same amount of response as heavier gauge strings when put on an Acoustic Guitar so I compensated for that on my Acoustic Guitar by shaving down the braces a little bit so that it'll vibrate more freely.

Comment: If you're happy with it, that's fine. I don't think you really made it sound like heavier strings though, because the bracing is only one minor part of the whole system which includes the bridge, top, and back and sides. Maybe you got a better sound by taking material from the bracing, but that doesn't mean you compensated completely for the lighter strings. You just made changes that you happen to like.

Comment: Regarding your question, what do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: What I mean by safe is if it can be done w/o ruining the instrument

Comment: Do you at all feel it's now a little too late to pose the question..? Some guitars may cope, others not so well. Sounds (to me) like not the cleverest move to make with any guitar. But we don't know what make/model, and the chances of someone else replicating what you did on the same guitar, to the same degree, are absolutely minimal.

Comment: What do you mean by “ruining”. Will the continue to work? Seems like you already know that it’s working (for you, for now). Will it retain its value on resale? Almost certainly not. Most people wouldn’t want to buy it at all after finding out about such work done it. Might it fail in the future? Maybe

Comment: Your last edit changed the question being asked, so you now have answers that answered a different question, and the question has become an "everybody share your opinion"-type, which is not what stackexchange was designed for.  You should edit to get the best version of the original question which was asked.

Comment: If you have a new question please ask it as a new question otherwise the answers don't fit

Answer (score 2):

Let's just take this from a mechanical engineering perspective: a rectangular beam of half thickness will have 1/8 of the stiffness.

That does not sound like you left a lot of the original brace function in place.

The answer to "is it safe?" will depend on whether the braces were mostly ornamental to start with.  On the inside of the instrument, that appears doubtful.

Answer (score 2):

Is it safe for anyone to do?

I used to listen into bluegrass guitar forums, and a lot of what they're talking about is getting the most of their dreadnaught-style acoustic guitars.

One controversial point is the [popsicle brace](http://www.bryankimsey.com/popsicle/), which is placed between the sound hole and the heel block. Pre-War dreads don't have them, but 1940 on, they're there. They are meant to stop top cracks, but the "good" dreadnaughts don't have them, and they block some of the higher frequencies (it is said), so some people take em out. Which voids the warranty.

The guitar as Martin built it is meant for a general player, and to survive the careless care of such a player. The modifications like your brace shaving and the popsicle brace removal mean it's more going to fit players like you, and the first time the next owner decides to try heavy strings, the guitar is done for. So, safe? I don't think anyone will be hurt if the top gives in under the 200 lb. or so in tension guitar strings give when in standard tuning, but they will be out an instrument. Mileage varies.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not! modifying the bracing requires you to open the instrument and glue it together again - hopefully without damaging the varnish. Most people probably do not even have the required tools and understanding of hide glue for this. So it is definitely not something that is "safe for anyone to do".

And while it is very much possible to tweak certain details of an instrument to get closer to what you want you need a very solid understanding of what makes the sound and how to tune that. And even then the person should be able to fix a mistake if he makes one. So unless the guitar is of little worth this is something that should be done by an expert.

Comment: You start saying  definitely not, and end saying it should be done by an expert. I'm confused.

Comment: @Tim The question is whether "this is safe for anyone to do". To this the answer is "definitely not". The other remark is about tuning certain things in a guitar, which should only be done by an expert.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to "can I [alter my instrument in any way]" is "If you have to ask, no." Most "non-undoable" operations should be done by luthiers. Now, the luthier is human and learned how to the given job correctly and confidently. For some skills, you could probably learn that too. But then you'd be confident about how to do it and whether it needs to be done.

So... "if you have to ask," take it to somebody.